# Override global Json.NET enum handling for one particular enum via decoration

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, serialization, json.net

I have a bunch of enums that I want Json.NET to serialize as camelcased strings. I have the following in my Global.asax.cs file and it's working great:

```
HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter { CamelCaseText = true });
```

This makes it so an enum like this:

```
public enum FavoriteWebSite {
    StackOverflow,
    GoogleNews
    // Etc
}
```

will serialize to values like "stackOverflow", "googleNews", etc.

However, I have a couple enums that are bitwise masks. To make this a simple example, suppose one looks like this:

```
public enum Hobbies {
    Walking = 0x01,
    Biking = 0x02,
    // Etc
}
```

What happens when I serialize instances of this enum depends on what kind of values are in it. For example:

```
Hobbies set1 = Hobbies.Walking;                  // Serializes as "walking" -- bad
Hobbies set2 = Hobbies.Walking | Hobbies.Biking; // Serializes as "3"       -- good!
```

I want to override the serialization on this enum to just serialize as an int, while leaving the global setting to use camelcased strings intact.

I tried removing the global configuration so that enums by default are serialized as ints, then adding only `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]` to the non-bitmask enums. However, this results in PascalCased, rather than CamelCased serialization for those. I didn't see any way to get the CamelCaseText attribute set when using StringEnumConverter in a method decoration like above.

So, to recap, the goal is:

1. Have single-value enums be serialized as pascalCased strings.
2. Have bitmask enums be serialized as ints.

Thank you!

Comment: So, you do want some enums to be serialized as `string` and some as `int`, right? This comment: `// Serializes as "walking" -- bad` made me think that you want all of them to be serialized as `int`.

Comment: By the way, goal number 1 is for the single-value enums to be serialized as camelCased strings, not pascalCased. Am I right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your main difficulty appears to be that you are not decorating your flag enums with [`FlagsAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), like so:

```
[Flags]
public enum Hobbies
{
    Walking = 0x01,
    Biking = 0x02,
    // Etc
}
```

This is the [recommended best practice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229058%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for flag enums:

> **Designing Flag Enums**
>
> √ DO apply the [System.FlagsAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to flag enums. Do not apply this attribute to simple enums.

See also [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229062.aspx).  If you don't do this, many enum-related .Net utilities may not work as expected for flag enumerations.

Having done this, [`StringEnumConverter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/StringEnumConverter.cs) will serialize flag enums with composite values as a set of comma-separated values instead of as the numeric value you are currently seeing:

> ```
> {
>   "Hobbies": "walking, biking"
> }
> ```

If you don't want this and still prefer to see default, numeric values for flag enums in your JSON, you can subclass `StringEnumConverter` to only convert non-flag enums:

```cs
public class NonFlagStringEnumConverter : StringEnumConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        if (!base.CanConvert(objectType))
            return false;
        return !HasFlagsAttribute(objectType);
    }

    static bool HasFlagsAttribute(Type objectType) 
    { 
        return Attribute.IsDefined(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) ?? objectType, typeof(System.FlagsAttribute));
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new NonFlagStringEnumConverter  { CamelCaseText = true });
```

This will cause Json.NET to fall back on any [global default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066904/json-net-global-settings) JSON converter for enums, or to numeric serialization if there is no applicable fallback.  Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tLVV7V).

Additionally, if you need to *supersede* a converter applied at a higher level and force numeric serialization for flag enums, use the following:

```cs
public class ForceNumericFlagEnumConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        if (!(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) ?? objectType).IsEnum)
            return false;
        return HasFlagsAttribute(objectType);
    }

    public override bool CanRead { get { return false; } }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    static bool HasFlagsAttribute(Type objectType) 
    { 
        return Attribute.IsDefined(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) ?? objectType, typeof(System.FlagsAttribute));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qsU9UY).

Comment: this didnt worked for me, flags are still converted to string names

Comment: I was not able to add json.net add reference but my code is like this;
https://dotnetfiddle.net/Yu2CRZ

Comment: @AFgone - I forked your fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/S52HB4, and I can't see a problem.  The `UserCan ability` object is being serialized as an integer `5` which is the required behavior for this converter: `[Flags]` enums to be serialized as integers, others as strings.  Maybe you have some global serializer settings that contain the "regular" string enum converter?  See [Json.net global settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16439024).

Comment: Yes I have global default settings however even if I provide new settings at that call isn't it used for that serialization?

Comment: @AFgone - No, if `CanConvert(Type objectType)` returns `false` from the locally provided converter then Json.NET falls back on the global converter.  Can you fork and update the fiddle to provide a [mcve]?

Comment: you are rirght, I used JsonSerializer.Create with settings and it worked. Many thanks for your help @dbc

Comment: Hopefully last question, I forked it. It is not working for "doeverything" any helps would be appreciated.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/air5pO

Comment: You should ask a separate question, but this appears to be a known bug with Json.NET: [Failure to deserialize ulong enum #2301](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2301).  (The value of `UserCan.DoEverything` is actually `ulong.MaxValue`.)

Comment: @AFgone - added update about superseding a global default converter.

Comment: so you resolved it? You are great! I'm asking another question as it was a big headache for me, and in this way more people can benefit from it. Please post this explainin what you do so that I accept as answer. here is the other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61740964/json-net-unable-to-deserialize-ulong-flag-type-enum @dbc

Comment: @AFgone - I resolved the issue with superseding a global converter here.  As for the other `ulong`-related issue, it's completely unrelated, and seems specific to using a `ulong` as the underlying type for an `enum`.   You might want to edit that question to include a [mcve] in the question itself.

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/11/12/override-json-net-serialization-settings-back-to-default/) blog post explains pretty well that there is not built in way to override global `StringEnumConverter`. You need write you own converter that *does nothing*, then when converting JSON.NET will go back to default converter for that type (which for enums is serializing to it's numeric value).

So in case you have global converter:

```cs
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter { CamelCaseText = true });
```

You can define this `ForceDefaultConverter` converter

```cs
public class ForceDefaultConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanRead => false;
    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

And use it on the property you want to override your *default* `StringEnumConverter`.

```cs
public class ExampleDto
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ForceDefaultConverter))]
    public TestEnum EnumValue { get; set; }
}
```

or on enum type itself if you want this numeric values when serializing all objects with this enum type.

```cs
[JsonConverter(typeof(ForceDefaultConverter))]
public enum TestEnum
{
    Foo = 1,
    Bar = 2
}
```