# JSON.NET Unable to deserialize ulong flag type enum

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a flag type of enum and I would like it to be serialized not as string but as number.
There is no problem about serializing but json.net unable to deserialize it.

```
public class ForceNumericFlagEnumConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        if (!(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) ?? objectType).IsEnum)
            return false;
        return HasFlagsAttribute(objectType);
    }

    public override bool CanRead { get { return false; } }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    static bool HasFlagsAttribute(Type objectType) 
    { 
        return Attribute.IsDefined(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) ?? objectType, typeof(System.FlagsAttribute));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            Test(UserCan.ChangeConf | UserCan.ForceOther);
            Test(UserCan.DoNothing);
            Test(UserCan.ForceOther);
            Test(UserCan.DoEverything);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Uncaught exception:");
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }

    static void Test(UserCan ability)
    {
        JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => GetGlobalJsonSettings();

        var settings = GetNEWJsonSettings();

        string jsonAbility = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ability, settings);
        Console.WriteLine("\nJSON serialization for {0} \"{1}\":", ability.GetType(), ability);
        Console.WriteLine(jsonAbility);

        ulong val;
        Assert.IsTrue(ulong.TryParse(jsonAbility, out val));

        var result1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserCan?>(jsonAbility, settings);
        var result2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserCan>(jsonAbility, settings);

        Assert.IsTrue(result1 == ability);
        Assert.IsTrue(result2 == ability);

        Assert.AreEqual("\"someValue\"", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(NonFlagEnum.SomeValue, settings));
    }

    public enum NonFlagEnum
    {
        SomeValue,
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum UserCan : ulong
    {
        DoNothing = 0,
        ChangeConf =               1 << 0,
        MonitorOthers =              1 << 1,
        ForceOther =                1 << 2,
        EditRemoveOthers =           1 << 3,

        DoEverything = unchecked((ulong)~0),
    }

    public static JsonSerializerSettings GetGlobalJsonSettings()
    {       
        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Converters = { new StringEnumConverter{ CamelCaseText = true } },
        };
        return settings;
    }

    public static JsonSerializerSettings GetNEWJsonSettings()
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.IgnoreAndPopulate,
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace, 
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
            Converters = { new ForceNumericFlagEnumConverter() },
        };
        return settings;
    }
}
```

You can see full code to create error here

https://dotnetfiddle.net/y0GnNf

> [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value 18446744073709551615 to type 'Program+UserCan'. Path '', line 1, position 20.]

Comment: underlying type of Enum is `int` not `long`, there is a problem of size here. you can change ``ulong`` to `uint`, will work fine.

Comment: In your demo, you write out `UserCan ability` object but not`string jsonAbility`. So maybe you did not test the serialization as you thought.

Comment: Problems start from `DoEverything = (ulong)(long.MaxValue) + 1`, `long.MaxValue` works fine for `long` based enum (`uint.MaxValue` works fine to for `uint` enum). Maybe bug in Newtonsoft serializer?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in the body of your question.

Comment: I need to use ulong as I have 50+ values to put inside flags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have encountered a known bug in Json.NET with `ulong`-type enumerations: *[Failure to deserialize ulong enum #2301](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2301)*

> Serialization of ulong enum values works fine,
>   but deserialization fails on large values.

As a workaround, if you are *not* using Json.NET's `StringEnumConverter`, you can add the following converter that correctly handles very large values for `ulong` enums:

```cs
public class FixedUlongEnumConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        var enumType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) ?? objectType;
        if (!enumType.IsEnum)
            return false;
        return Enum.GetUnderlyingType(enumType) == typeof(ulong);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var nullableUnderlying = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType);
        var enumType = nullableUnderlying ?? objectType;
        var isNullable = nullableUnderlying != null;
        switch (reader.MoveToContentAndAssert().TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.Null:
                if (!isNullable)
                    throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Null value for {0}", objectType));
                return null;

            case JsonToken.Integer:
                if (reader.ValueType == typeof(System.Numerics.BigInteger))
                {
                    var bigInteger = (System.Numerics.BigInteger)reader.Value;
                    if (bigInteger >= ulong.MinValue && bigInteger <= ulong.MaxValue)
                    {
                        return Enum.ToObject(enumType, checked((ulong)bigInteger));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Value {0} is too large for enum {1}", bigInteger, enumType));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return Enum.ToObject(enumType, reader.Value);
                }

            default:
                throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Unexpected token {0}", reader.TokenType));          
        }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader MoveToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)       // Skip past beginning of stream.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment) // Skip past comments.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        return reader;
    }

    public static JsonReader ReadAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (!reader.Read())
            throw new JsonReaderException("Unexpected end of JSON stream.");
        return reader;
    }
}
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PjmR0E).

And if you *are* using Json.NET's `StringEnumConverter` but might sometimes get numeric values for enums anyway, replace it with this fixed version:

```cs
public class FixedUlongStringEnumConverter : StringEnumConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.MoveToContentAndAssert().TokenType == JsonToken.Integer && reader.ValueType == typeof(System.Numerics.BigInteger))
        {
            // Todo: throw an exception if !this.AllowIntegerValues
            // https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter_AllowIntegerValues.htm
            var enumType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) ?? objectType;
            if (Enum.GetUnderlyingType(enumType) == typeof(ulong))
            {
                var bigInteger = (System.Numerics.BigInteger)reader.Value;
                if (bigInteger >= ulong.MinValue && bigInteger <= ulong.MaxValue)
                {
                    return Enum.ToObject(enumType, checked((ulong)bigInteger));
                }
            }
        }
        return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
    }
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader MoveToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)       // Skip past beginning of stream.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment) // Skip past comments.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        return reader;
    }

    public static JsonReader ReadAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (!reader.Read())
            throw new JsonReaderException("Unexpected end of JSON stream.");
        return reader;
    }
}
```

Now, you have an additional requirement to serialize `[Flags]` enums, and only `[Flags]` enums, as integers.  You can do this by further subclassing the above converter as follows:

```cs
public class ForceNumericFlagEnumConverter : FixedUlongStringEnumConverter
{
    static bool HasFlagsAttribute(Type objectType) 
    { 
        return Attribute.IsDefined(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType) ?? objectType, typeof(System.FlagsAttribute));
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var enumType = value.GetType();
        if (HasFlagsAttribute(enumType))
        {
            var underlyingType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(enumType);
            var underlyingValue = Convert.ChangeType(value, underlyingType);
            writer.WriteValue(underlyingValue);
        }
        else
        {
            base.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer);
        }
    }   
}
```

The workaround requires support for [`BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger) which was introduced in .NET Framework 4.0.

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/X1zvGb).

Comment: perfect, many thanks. But I have an issue, I want to use numeric conversion, not string based conversion, as my clients are desktop based, and they may have an old version of enum, which means if there is a new flag defined at server side, deserialization fails if I use string converter. Any help to use this with ulong numeric converter?

Comment: Not entirely sure I know what you mean.  Do you mean you want to use numeric values for all enums not just flag enums?

Comment: yes instead of string de/serialization I want to have numeric values

Comment: @AFgone - that wasn't in your original question if I recall correctly.  But I added `FixedUlongEnumConverter` because it seems a reasonable extension.

Answer (score 0):

Change `ulong` to `uint`    :

```
public enum UserCan : uint
{
    DoNothing = 0,
    ChangeConf =               1 << 0,
    MonitorOthers =              1 << 1,
    ForceOther =                1 << 2,
    EditRemoveOthers =           1 << 3,

    DoEverything = unchecked((uint)~0),
}
```

Working fiddle:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/DyQ2R7

Comment: I can't because I need to set at least 60 flags