# How to Convert Custom Attribute into Json String

Tags: json.net

Is there any way to convert any of my custom attribute(s) into something when I call the JsonConvert.SerializeObject(...) function? For example, I have a class:

```
class A
{
  [UnitAttribute("---")]
  public double? Ratio { get; set; } 
}
```

When serialize any instance of such class, is there any way to put the value of the UnitAttribute into the Json string?

I found there is a IAttributeProvider interface in the API. But it seems the serialize function doesn't really use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing to do would be to create a [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) that adds the attribute text (which I assume corresponds to units, in this case) and attach the converter to the property:

```
class A
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(UnitConverter), new object [] { "mm" })]
    public double? Ratio { get; set; }
}

public class UnitConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public string Units { get; set; }

    string UnitsPostfix { get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(Units) ? string.Empty : " " + Units; } }

    public UnitConverter(string units)
    {
        this.Units = units;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); // Not called when applied directly to a property.
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jvalue = JValue.Load(reader);
        if (jvalue.Type == JTokenType.String)
        {
            var s = (string)jvalue;
            if (s.EndsWith(Units))
                jvalue = (JValue)s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf(Units)).Trim();
        }
        return jvalue.ToObject(objectType);

    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jvalue = JValue.FromObject(value);
        if (jvalue.Type == JTokenType.Null)
            jvalue.WriteTo(writer);
        else
            writer.WriteValue((string)jvalue + UnitsPostfix);
    }
}
```

Notice I can pass the unit string directly to the converter's constructor in the attribute declaration.

If you have lots of fields and properties in your code base with `UnitAttribute` and want to apply the converter to all of them automatically, you could create a custom [`IContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomContractResolver.htm) derived from an existing contract resolver such as [`DefaultContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver.htm) that applies the necessary converter:

```
public class UnitContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (property.Converter == null && property.MemberConverter == null)
        {
            var attr = property.AttributeProvider.GetAttributes(typeof(UnitAttribute), true).Cast<UnitAttribute>().Where(a => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Name)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (attr != null)
            {
                property.Converter = property.MemberConverter = new UnitConverter(attr.Name);
            }
        }
        return property;
    }
}
```

You can either use the the contract resolver explicitly, like so:

```
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { ContractResolver = new UnitContractResolver() };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a, settings);
        Debug.WriteLine(json);
        var a11 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(json, settings);
        Debug.Assert(a.Ratio == a.Ratio);
```

Or set it in the [Json.net global settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066904/json-net-global-settings) for automatic use.