# NewtonJson DateTime format serialization

Tags: c#, datetime, json.net

I'm using NewtonJson.NET in order to de/serialize my classes to json format.

I don't know why, but it serializes DateTime values like this example:  `2015-07-23T10:39:31.0017599+02:00`.

My server understands ISO8601 format: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`.

I'm figuring out the problem is on milliseconds `SSS` part.

How could I change it?

I'd need to set this configuration as a globally form, so, no in each field for example. I'd like NewtonJson always serialize DateTime values as ISO8601 format.

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 2):

ISO 8601 [is default for Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm) since 4.5 version. Both what you get and what you want is ISO 8601, in latter case `Z` means that time is in UTC:

```
// This is equal to 2015-07-23T12:22:17.7902881+03:00
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.Now);

// This is equal to 2015-07-23T09:22:18.0585302Z
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.UtcNow);
```

To tell Json.NET to interpret `DateTime` as UTC you can [use global settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16439024/2594597):

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
};
```

Or local settings:

```
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.Now, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
}));
```

Comment: Thanks! That's it! Am I be able to set .Net standard DateTime as UTC? Or I always I need to specify it programatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the format converter for example by annotating  the property:

```
[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(CustomDateTimeConverter))]
public DateTime? DateTime1;

class CustomDateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public CustomDateTimeConverter()
    {
        DateTimeFormat = "MM.dd.yyyy";//specify your format
    }
}
```