# Newtonsoft JsonConvert Complex Number Issue

Tags: c#, json, json.net, complex-numbers

I'm using Newtonsoft JsonConvert.SerializeObject and JsonConvert.DeserializeObject on quite a complicated DTO.  Within this, I have some Complex numbers (System.Numerics).  Everything works perfectly except for the Complex numbers.

The numbers serialise fine, resulting in:

```
{
    ... lots of JSON here ...   
    "Electrical": {     
        ... lots of JSON objects ... 
            "Z1": {
                "Real": 0.0017923713150000001,
                "Imaginary": 0.0,
                "Magnitude": 0.0017923713150000001,
                "Phase": 0.0
            },
            "Z0": {
                "Real": 0.0017923713150000001,
                "Imaginary": 0.0,
                "Magnitude": 0.0017923713150000001,
                "Phase": 0.0
            }
        }
    ... lots of JSON .. here ...
}
```

The problem is in the deserialization, where the complex number returned is full of zeros, for example:

```
calculation.Electrical.Impedance.Z0
{(0, 0)}
    Imaginary: 0
    Magnitude: 0
    Phase: 0
    Real: 0
    m_imaginary: 0
    m_real: 0
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this would be great.

Comment: You might just need to implement a custom `JsonConverter` class.  Take a look at the answer here for a similar example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051206/handling-decimal-values-in-newtonsoft-json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither Json.NET nor the [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/) have a predefined format for complex numbers, and so Json.NET will serialize all the properties of a [`Complex`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Numerics/System/Numerics/Complex.cs), generating the output you see.  To get clean JSON with just the necessary data, you will need to write a [custom `JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) that serializes a `Complex` from and to JSON.

However, what format should be used?  Options might include:

1. As an array: `[0.0017923713150000001,0.0]`.
2. As an object with `"Real"` and `"Imaginary"` properties: `{"Real":0.0017923713150000001,"Imaginary":0.0}`.
3. In [math.js format](http://mathjs.org/docs/core/serialization.html): `{"mathjs":"Complex","re":0.0017923713150000001,"im":0.0}`.

Here are converters for each of these formats:

```
public abstract class ComplexConverterBase : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Complex) || objectType == typeof(Complex?);
    }
}

public class ComplexArrayConverter : ComplexConverterBase
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var array = serializer.Deserialize<double[]>(reader);
        if (array.Length != 2)
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Invalid complex number array of length {0}", array.Length));
        }
        return new Complex(array[0], array[1]);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var complex = (Complex)value;
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        writer.WriteValue(complex.Real);
        writer.WriteValue(complex.Imaginary);
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }
}

public class ComplexObjectConverter : ComplexConverterBase
{
    // By using a surrogate type, we respect the naming conventions of the serializer's contract resolver.
    class ComplexSurrogate
    {
        public double Real { get; set; }
        public double Imaginary { get; set; }

        public static implicit operator Complex(ComplexSurrogate surrogate)
        {
            if (surrogate == null)
                return default(Complex);
            return new Complex(surrogate.Real, surrogate.Imaginary);
        }

        public static implicit operator ComplexSurrogate(Complex complex)
        {
            return new ComplexSurrogate { Real = complex.Real, Imaginary = complex.Imaginary };
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        return (Complex)serializer.Deserialize<ComplexSurrogate>(reader);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, (ComplexSurrogate)(Complex)value);
    }
}

public class ComplexMathJSConverter : ComplexConverterBase
{
    // Serialize in math.js format
    // http://mathjs.org/docs/core/serialization.html
    // By using a surrogate type, we respect the naming conventions of the serializer's contract resolver.
    class ComplexSurrogate
    {
        [JsonProperty(Order = 1)]
        public double re { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(Order = 2)]
        public double im { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(Order = 0)]
        public string mathjs { get { return "Complex"; } }

        public static implicit operator Complex(ComplexSurrogate surrogate)
        {
            if (surrogate == null)
                return default(Complex);
            return new Complex(surrogate.re, surrogate.im);
        }

        public static implicit operator ComplexSurrogate(Complex complex)
        {
            return new ComplexSurrogate { re = complex.Real, im = complex.Imaginary };
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        return (Complex)serializer.Deserialize<ComplexSurrogate>(reader);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, (ComplexSurrogate)(Complex)value);
    }
}
```

Then, you would serialize as follows:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    // Add a complex converter to the Converts array.  
    // Use one of ComplexArrayConverter, ComplexMathJSConverter and ComplexObjectConverter
    Converters = { new ComplexArrayConverter() },
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(calculation, settings);
```

To use the converter in global settings, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13274625/3744182) for Web API or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15066904/3744182) when calling the serializer directly.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rt7Y2k).

Comment: dbc,  thanks for the clear and detailed explanation.  It worked perfectly.  Your answer was a great help after many hours of searching.