# ASP.NET Core 3.0 System.Text.Json Camel Case Serialization

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, system.text.json

In ASP.NET Core 3.0 Web API project, how do you specify [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=netcore-3.0) serialization options to serialize/deserialize Pascal Case properties to Camel Case and vice versa automatically?

Given a model with Pascal Case properties such as:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

And code to use System.Text.Json to deserialize a JSON string to type of `Person` class:

```
var json = "{\"firstname\":\"John\",\"lastname\":\"Smith\"}";
var person = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Person>(json);
```

Does not successfully deserialize unless [JsonPropertyName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=netcore-3.0) is used with each property like:

```
public class Person
{
    [JsonPropertyName("firstname")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("lastname")]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

I tried the following in `startup.cs`, but it did not help in terms of still needing `JsonPropertyName`:

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
});

// also the following given it's a Web API project

services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options => {
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
        });
```

How can you set Camel Case serialize/deserialize in ASP.NET Core 3.0 using the new System.Text.Json namespace?

Thanks!

Comment: For the record, your Person class has properties in Sentence case. Pascal case would be FirstName and LastName

Comment: I got this behavior by default in .net 6. Trying to get rid of it :D

Answer (score 151, accepted):

`AddJsonOptions()` would config `System.Text.Json` only for MVC. If you want to use `JsonSerializer` in your own code you should pass the config to it.

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
};

var json = "{\"firstname\":\"John\",\"lastname\":\"Smith\"}";
var person = JsonSerializer.Parse<Person>(json, options);
```

Comment: There is no way to specify serialization options for the entire project/application with System.Text.Json? This was trivial before System.Text.Json

Comment: I don't think so. You need to pass the settings

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky - no, see [Is There A Way To Globally Set Default Options For System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58331479/3744182).

Comment: [This is possible with Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16439024/542251)

Comment: JsonSerializer does not contain property called Parse ???

Comment: See this link if you need something outside the "built in" ones (like JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1#use-a-custom-json-property-naming-policy     Note, the JsonNamingPolicy can be applied to the json-ELEMENT-names and/or the json-VALUES.

Comment: In .NET 8 I was getting an error when using this and needed to add another property to JsonSerializerOptions: TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver()

Answer (score 66):

If you want `camelCase` serialization use this code in *Startup.cs*: (for example firstName)

```
services.AddControllers()
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
        });
```

If you want `PascalCase` serialization use this code in *Startup.cs*: (for example FirstName)

```
services.AddControllers()
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy= null;
        );
```

Comment: Setting `PropertyNamingPolicy` to `null` resolved it. I first tried removing the line altogether  (it was camelCase before), but that does not work - you need to set it to null =)

Answer (score 56):

In `startup.cs`:

```
// keeps the casing to that of the model when serializing to json
// (default is converting to camelCase)
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
```

This means you don't need to import newtonsoft.json.

The only other option for `options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy` is `JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase`. There do not seem to be any other `JsonNamingPolicy` naming policy options, such as snake_case or PascalCase.

Comment: This worked for me. FTR, I didn't have .AddMvc() in my services before this, only adding it so AddJsonOptions could be added. All my server-client serialisation issues went away.....

Answer (score 24):

You can use `PropertyNameCaseInsensitive`. You need to pass it as a parameter to the deserializer.

```
var json = "{\"firstname\":\"John\",\"lastname\":\"Smith\"}";
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
var person = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Person>(json, options);
```

which (from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.propertynamecaseinsensitive?view=netcore-3.0)):

> Gets or sets a value that determines whether a property's name uses a
> case-insensitive comparison during deserialization. The default value
> is false

So, it doesn't specify camelCase or PascalCase but it will use case-insensitive comparison.

---

The below will configure System.Text.Json for Json passed through a controller endpoint:

```
services.AddControllers()
        .AddJsonOptions(options => {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
         });
```

Comment: FYI: `PropertyNameCaseInsensitive`  is only for incoming JSON. ` options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy= null;` will serialise outgoing JSON PascalCase

Comment: What @PiotrKula says is true... PropertyNameCaseInsensitive is only used on incoming JSON payloads, but in addition to PropertyNamingPolicy dictating the rules on outgoing JSON payload creation during serialization, it ALSO expects that incoming payloads will mach the policy on deserialization; if it does not, your deserialization class members will have default values - this where PropertyNameCaseInsensitive fills the gap, it will allow deserialization to succeed regardless the incoming payload casing.

Answer (score 13):

You can still set it application wide by installing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` Nuget Package, which allows you to use the previous Json serializer implementation :

```
services.AddControllers()
        .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
        });
```

Credits to Poke, answer found here :
[Where did IMvcBuilder AddJsonOptions go in .Net Core 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55666826/where-did-imvcbuilder-addjsonoptions-go-in-net-core-3-0)

Answer (score 9):

### .NET Core 7 Minimal API solution

To prevent pascal case properties from being renamed to camel case during serialization, use the ConfigureHttpJsonOptions method of the builder's service property.

```
builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
```

To force conversion to camel case (default behavior), use:

```
builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this!

In `StartUp.cs` inside the `ConfigureServices` method write:

```
 services.AddMvc()
                    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy
                     = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase);
```

You need namespaces such as  `Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization` & `System.Text.Json`

Comment: This would be better if you document where this should go AND  how this differs from similar answers, how would we know you did not just copy those?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I have done that now. Thanks for feed back.