# ASP.NET Core 3.0 configure controllers to return pascal case objects

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core 3, there seems to be only one options when you are adding json options:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers()
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase);
}
```

I'm wondering if I'm missing an option to return my objects in PascalCase rather than camelCase. I don't know why but I feel like this should be included in the base libraries

Quick edit:
[Similar question about serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58476681/asp-net-core-3-0-system-text-json-camel-case-serialization), I would say that this question is different because my question was around the object returned form the api, where as the question referenced is about serializing an object outside of the ASP .NET core pipeline.

Comment: simply create custom policy https://www.rickvandenbosch.net/blog/creating-a-custom-jsonnamingpolicy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions that I have found here, one you can define your own `JsonNamingPolicy`:

```
public class JsonPascalCaseNamingPolicy : JsonNamingPolicy
    {
        public override string ConvertName(string name)
        {
            return name;
        }
    }
```

Or you can include the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` package and add a default contract resolver:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers()
                .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
        }
```

Comment: Just in case anyone comes across this, you cannot AddJsonOptions as AddingNewtonJson will override Json options as mentioned |https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/12/19/using-newtonsoft-json-in-net-core-3-projects/. This is the correct answer if you are using NewtonsoftJson

Answer (score 0):

If you want PascalCase serialization use this code in Startup.cs: (for example FirstName)

```
services.AddControllers()
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy= null;
        );
```

For more information, please visit this link: [Asp.Net Core 3 Serialization settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59892130/8810311)