# Configuring System.Text.Json Camel Case in ASP.Net Core 3.x DI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, json.net

I want to configure camlecase for JSON serialization in ASP.NET Core.
I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58476681/asp-net-core-3-0-system-text-json-camel-case-serialization) solution. But it just works on MVC not WebApi.

So I've tested:

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options => {
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
        });
```

And it is not working in WebApi projects.

So the question is: How to configure `Camel Case` in ASP.NET Core WebApi projects.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

In Startup.cs file

```
public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(j =>
        {
            j.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
            {
                NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
            };
        });
}
```

Comment: This is a Newtonsoft solution, OP asked for a System.Text.Json solution.