# getting json error when invoking asp.net core action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman

I got this simple request to an action in an asp.net core controller.

Controller:

```
[ApiController]
public class SystemAPIController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("systemAPI/SetCulture")]
    public async Task SetCulture([FromBody] string culture)
    {
        this.HttpContext.Session.SetString("Culture", culture);
    }
}
```

The JSON in the body:

```
{
    "culture": "nb-NO"
}
```

I get the following error when invoking the action using postman:

> ```
>         "The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."
> ```

Comment: We need to see the text response to help solve issue.  The response is not matching the your expect controller response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a class which will represent the json structure:

```
public class Request
{
    public string culture {get;set;}
}
```

And use it as incoming action parameter:

```
[HttpPost("systemAPI/SetCulture")]
public async Task SetCulture([FromBody] Request request)
{
    this.HttpContext.Session.SetString("Culture", request.culture);
}
```

Also common naming convention [for properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members#names-of-properties) in C# is PascalCasing but to support it you will either set up it [globally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58476761/2501279) or use `JsonPropertyNameAttribute` per property:

```
public class Request
{
    [JsonPropertyName("culture")]
    public string Culture {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: created the structure at it worked perfect

Comment: @SteinTheRuler was glad to help!