# Azure Function with Cosmos DB binding returning formatted DateTime?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I ran into some difficulties storing a DateTime object given as a string in CosmosDB. To make sure it's not related to serialization of DateTime objects, I'm currently working with **strings only**.

My stored document in the database looks as follows:

```
{
    "available": true,
    "id": "391a802c-ac42-443b-860a-8ab7061b389c",
    "checked_date": "2020-06-04T12:53:29.4625341Z",
    "code": "AAAA",
    "_rid": "w6VGAOSKaJABAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/w6VGAA==/colls/w6VGAOSKaJA=/docs/w6VGAOSKaJABAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"00000000-0000-0000-3a70-96abc3ea01d6\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1591275829
}
```

I'm using a very simple function to query it:

```
[FunctionName("GetObject")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> GetObject(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "object/{code}")] HttpRequest req,
    [CosmosDB(
        databaseName: "database01",
        collectionName: "objecttable",
        ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBString",
        SqlQuery = "SELECT c.id, c.code, c.available, c.checked_date FROM objecttable c WHERE LOWER(c.code)=LOWER({code})")] IEnumerable<ObjectEntity> entities,
                ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("GetObject function processed a request.");
    return new JsonResult(entities);
}
```

The ObjectEntity class looks like this:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class ObjectEntity
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "available")]
    public bool Available {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "checked_date")]
    public string CheckedDate {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "code")]
    public string Code{get; set;}
}
```

When storing some arbitrary string data in the field "checked_date", the string just gets returned as expected. When I store a string like "2020-06-04T12:53:29.4625341Z", I get "06/04/2020 12:53:29" returned instead - without applying any deserialization, typecasting or something similar.

Using the CosmosDB Explorer, I see the correct string representation.

This is not related to the return object of the Azure function, the problem occurs within the function already. If I set a breakpoint within the function I can see that the strings in the entities object are already messed up.

What am I doing wrong here? Is the CosmosDB binding messing up my string here?

---

Update:
I've set the CosmosDB connection mode to "Direct" and traced the request using Fiddler. It seems that CosmosDB does indeed return the correct string in the response body:

```
{"_rid":"w6VGAOSKaJA=","Documents":[{"id":"391a802c-ac42-443b-860a-8ab7061b389c","code":"AAAA","available":true,"checked_date":"2020-06-04T12:53:29.4625341Z"}],"_count":1}
```

So the issue has to be related to the binding itself or the deserialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is probably related to the SDK using the default Newtonsoft.Json serializer settings which parse strings to datetime (https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/issues/235 and https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DateParseHandling.htm), `DateParseHandling.None` would solve it.

The bindings do not let you define how the `DocumentClient` is initialized sadly. One alternative would be to maintain your own instance instead of using the binding (which I guess is more code in the end). `DocumentClient` has a constructor that let's you specify an instance of `JsonSerializerSettings`.

Make sure the instance is created following the [Functions' guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections#static-clients).

Another alternative would be to set it globally but that would affect all the other code that is using Newtonsoft.Json: [Json.net global settings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15066904/5641598)

Finally, you could create a custom converter over the property that just outputs the text as-is.

Comment: Thank you! Following your hints, I found the following bug report:

https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/862

The behavior is intended by Json.Net so I definitely need to specify my own settings for serialization which leads to using a DocumentClient other than the one created by the binding.