# Newtonsoft.json ignore Json property attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

`Newtonsoft.Json` ignore `JsonProperty` attributes while serializing object to json in .NET Framework 4.5 legacy webapi project.

Properties in my class looks as simple as this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class A
{

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "workflow")]
    public string Workflow { get; private set; }

}
```

Then i am executing serializing:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var asJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    a,
    Formatting.None,
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
    });
```

And output looks like this:

```
{
    "Workflow": "18",
}
```

instead of:

```
{
    "workflow": "18"
},
```

Based on `JsonProperty`. My question is, why newtonsoft serializer ignore `Jsonproperty` attributes in .NET Framework 4.5 web api project?

Comment: Please add all the detail required to reproduce the problem

Comment: @stuartd What do you need can you tell me please?

Comment: You  need to put the full json and full class, not just one property

Comment: OK got it, check this now

Comment: Thanks, but it is not valid, can you post a valid json pls, and you can not add property attribute to a class

Comment: Edited, now you can get the clue better

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Here's a complete piece of code that compiles (you have provided incomplete code...) https://gist.github.com/jskeet/b2a3738b426f6deaa0d073126c0dac8f The output is `{"workflow":"test"}`.

Comment: I can't reproduce either, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/UYwntN.  Two possibilities: 1) You are mixing version of Json.NET and the `[JsonProperty]` applied to your model is from a different DLL version that the one being used by the call to `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`.  2) You are actually using System.Text.Json to serialize without realizing it.

Comment: A third possibility to add to @dbc is that you are actually using `JsonPropertyName` which is for `System.Text.Json` but you are deserializing using JSON.Net

Comment: Or 4) You have some [global default value for `JsonSerializerSettings`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DefaultSettings.htm) that is interfering with `JsonPropertyAttribute.PropertyName` somehow.  What is the value of `JsonConvert.DefaultSettings`?  See: [Json.net global settings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15066904/3744182).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you examples are not valid, this is working for me

```
    var a = new A {Workflow="18"};

    var asJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        a,
        Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None,
        new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
        });
}


public class A
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "workflow")]
    public string Workflow { get;  set; }
}
```

result

```
{"workflow":"18"}
```

the same is with this class

```
public class A
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "workflow")]
    public string Workflow { get; private set; }
    
    public A(string workflow)
    {
        Workflow=workflow;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea but believe me, in my case it is not working. Do you have an idea what to check wehn these properties not working?

Comment: @michasaucer - *Yea but believe me, in my case it is not working.* -- then please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72859929/edit) your question to share a [mcve].  That can't be your real code because your class `A` has no public setter and thus `Workflow` could never be set to `"18"`.  See [ask].  Serge made a reasonable guess as to how to fix your example to make it work but it could be your real code is what is causing the problem.

Comment: @michasaucer The best thing is to post your original. You don't need to post all properties, just a couple would be enough.